# Tool to archive old data from MySQL database, without losing the relation

Tags: database, mysql, archiving

I have a MySQL database that is rapidly increasing. This database contains all transactional data. I need to archive the database and move the two years old data into the archive so that the production database becomes lighter without losing the relation. Is there any automatic tool for doing that or I need to manually do that? What giants companies do for archiving their huge database every day?

Comment: Just as a remark: "Giant companies" don't use MySQL for their "giant databases". They use something like Oracle (often Exadata) with partitioning. So their solutions wouldn't apply to you.

Comment: What do you mean by "without losing the relation"? Does the "archived" data need to still be accessible in some way? If yes, for what operations?

Comment: No, I dont need to access the old data, I wanted to mean delete old data but keep the data relation as it is.